A Comprehensive Masterpiece on History of Science
I am looking for books that are very technical on History of Science as a whole. It should be encyclopedia-typed, and written by prominent historians. It should also include philosophy of science type of discussion.
An example in the field of "pure" history would be Will Durant's story of civilization. My question is: Does there exists such books in History of Science?

The Cambridge History of Science

There is such a kind of masterpiece you refer to but, unfortunately, it is in Italian and, as far as I know, not translated except in Spanish (I don’t know if completely), I suppose because of its huge number of pages.
But I mention it here because it is an important work and in the case it could be useful to someone who can read Italian or Spanish.
This is the famous Storia del pensiero filosofico e scientifico (History of Scientific and Philosophical Thought) by Ludovico Geymonat and other prominent historians and philosophers of science.
It is  a 'monumental' history of science,  together with philosophy, very in-depth and detailed, composed of seven volumes, for more than 5,000 pages overall, ranging from antiquity to XX century.

The closest I can think of is Charles Gillispie's Dictionary of Scientific Biography (Gillispie is the editor).  There is a number of valuable articles there, such as the article on Cauchy by Hans Freudenthal.

Grattan-Guinness's work on the 19th century runs into 1600 pages and is a fine contribution from a respected historian:

Grattan-Guinness, Ivor Convolutions in French mathematics, 1800–1840: from the calculus and mechanics to mathematical analysis and mathematical physics.

The work is in 3 volumes and was published in 1990 by Birkhäuser Verlag, Basel (currently owned by Springer, I believe).

On the "very technical" side, but under a less-than-overarching sweep, there is a classic gem on the history of Einstein's physics and its specific background, effects and significance. It was written by an eminent professional physicist, and eschews the bloviatory hagiography model bedeviling such efforts:
Subtle Is the Lord: The Science and the Life of Albert Einstein
by Abraham Pais  (Oxford University Press 2005); ISBN-13  978-0192806727
In the same masterful vein, a similar book by the same author on modern physics is largely written  for "professionals", i.e.  a far cry from the routine "popular science" clones with their repulsive & unsound bloviation of standard overviews:
Inward Bound: Of Matter and Forces in the Physical World
by Abraham Pais (Clarendon Press   1988); ISBN-13  978-0198519973

Something that may align well with your request is Olby, Cantor, Christie, and Hodge, Companion to the History of Modern Science, a large book, sort of a collection of encyclopedic articles covering topics ranging from the philosophy of science, the historiography of science, and the practice of science history. It can be obtained relatively inexpensively too, and is quite comprehensive.

David Wootton's magisterial 2015 The Invention of Science is where I would start.
https://www.inventionofscience.com/
Wootton has some very constructive comments and criticisms of Thomas Kuhn's The Structure of Scientific Revolutions, the modern foundation for theories of scientific evolution in paradigms.
https://www.google.co.th/books/edition/The_Structure_of_Scientific_Revolutions/3eP5Y_OOuzwC?hl=en&gbpv=0
Herbert Butterfield's 1965 The Origins of Modern Science is a classic.
https://www.google.co.th/books/edition/The_Origins_of_Modern_Science/E8gb_iclt-sC?hl=en&gbpv=0
